# MYSQL group by hour with 2 column counts

Tags: mysql, grouping

I am creating a dashboard for my service desk and am looking to create a logged vs resolved incidents graph but cant work out what query will give me the results I need in one step (eventually will be executed by php)

The data I want to get my results from are:
Logdatex - a unix timestamp of when the ticket was logged
Resolve_datex - a unix timestamp of when the ticket was logged

My data looks like (A small sample as I am working with over 200 records/day):

```
|| *logdatex* || *resolve_datex* ||
|| 1463734913 ||    1531738806   ||
|| 1476695541 ||    1532698820   ||
|| 1528727293 ||    1528729503   ||
|| 1501488766 ||    1529314520   ||
|| 1528730682 ||    1528730809   ||
|| 1507122741 ||    1531739076   ||
|| 1528725481 ||    1528793556   ||
|| 1507300496 ||    1529063535   ||
|| 1511867374 ||    1529314392   ||
|| 1528724000 ||    1528810247   ||
```

The kind output I am looking for is:

```
+------+--------+----------+
| Hour | Logged | Resolved |
+------+--------+----------+
|  8   |   19   |   0      |
|  9   |   25   |   15     |
|  10  |   23   |   21     |
|  11  |   20   |   29     |
|  12  |   18   |   33     |
+------+--------+----------+
```

I can quite easily get the information using 2 queries but want to only use one. The 2 queries I can use to get the data are:
1.

```
SELECT HOUR (from_unixtime(logdatex)), COUNT(HOUR (from_unixtime(logdatex)))
FROM mytable
WHERE from_unixtime(logdatex) > NOW() - INTERVAL 11 HOUR
GROUP BY HOUR (from_unixtime(logdatex))
```

2.

```
SELECT HOUR (from_unixtime(resolve_datex)), COUNT(HOUR (from_unixtime(resolve_datex)))
FROM mytable
WHERE from_unixtime(resolve_datex) > NOW() - INTERVAL 11 HOUR
GROUP BY HOUR (from_unixtime(resolve_datex))
```

Comment: Please ensure that your expected output matches with your sample dataset given. Also, edit the question to add your latest code efforts

Comment: i doubt those queries work MySQL normally does not allow a space in a function call like `HOUR (`...

Comment: The queries work using HeidiSQL 9.5 on MYSQL 4.0.16 (very old version i know but i cant upgrade it)

Comment: You could use `right join` to add the result of the second query to the first, couldn't you?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query. Hope it helps you.

```
                            SELECT FIELD, SUM(cnt)
                            FROM (
                              SELECT HOUR (FROM_UNIXTIME(logdatex)) AS FIELD, COUNT(HOUR (FROM_UNIXTIME(logdatex))) AS cnt
                              FROM mytable
                              GROUP BY HOUR (FROM_UNIXTIME(logdatex))
                              UNION ALL
                              SELECT HOUR (FROM_UNIXTIME(resolve_datex)) AS FIELD, COUNT(HOUR (FROM_UNIXTIME(resolve_datex))) AS cnt
                              FROM mytable
                              GROUP BY HOUR (FROM_UNIXTIME(resolve_datex))
                            ) AS combined_table
                            GROUP BY FIELD
```

Answer (score 0):

So... after a lot of looking around and a lot of swearing at my PC I have found that using MYSQL 4.0.16 this is not possible as it doesn't support nested select statements. You can get most of the way using case statements but cant group the hour columns together. It looks like i am going to learn more PHP to get the results from the 2 queries and display in a single table.